# Create an object based on the data from another object (add one "level")

Tags: javascript

After my glorious fails with loops I came here for help.
Basically I want to "add new level" to my target JSON, based on data from source.

Base JSON:

```
var base = [
    {    
        children: [
            {
                children: [],
                parent: "ROOT",
                title: "Tenant1",
                typeName: "Tenants"
            },
            {
                children: [],
                parent: "ROOT",
                title: "Tenant2",
                typeName: "Tenants"
            }
        ],
        parent: null,
        title: "ROOT",
        typeName: null,
    }
];
```

Target JSON:

```
var target = [
    {
        children: [
            {
                children: [
                    {
                         children: [],
                         parent: "Tenants",
                         title: "Tenant1",
                         typeName: "Tenants"
                     },
                     {
                         children: [],
                         parent: "Tenants", // <---- here
                         title: "Tenant2",
                         typeName: "Tenants"
                     }
                ],
                parent: "ROOT",             // <---- here
                title: "Tenants",
                typeName: "Tenants"
            }
        ],
        parent: null,
        title: "ROOT",
        typeName: null
    }
];
```

The new level needs to have parent as ROOT, and "old" children (now leafs) have to have parent set to their "typeName".

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, **post a [mcve] of your attempt** and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this works fine for you.
I've made a recursive function that once it finds the parent of the element that you pass to add, it passes the children of the parent element to the current element and adds the new element.

```js
var base = [
    {    
        children: [
            {
                children: [],
                parent: "ROOT",
                title: "Tenant1",
                typeName: "Tenants"
            },
            {
                children: [],
                parent: "ROOT",
                title: "Tenant2",
                typeName: "Tenants"
            }
        ],
        parent: null,
        title: "ROOT",
        typeName: null,
    },
];

let element = {
  parent: "ROOT",
  title: "Tenants",
  typeName: "Tenants"
};

function addNewLevel(list, element) {
 if(list.length) {
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
     if(list[i].title === element.parent) {
       element.children = list[i].children;
        for (var j = 0; j < element.children.length; j++) {
         element.children[j].parent = element.title;
        }
        list[i].children = [element];
      } else if(list[i].children.length) {
       let newList = addNewLevel(list[i].children, element);
        list[i].children = newList;
        return list[i];
      }
    }
    return list;
  }
}

console.log('New Level List', addNewLevel(base, element));
```